# Render information from php object?

Tags: php

How can I render the title and description from the `$description` object in PHP? The object contains the information which I need but I failed to render them in the browser.

```
<?php
require 'function.php';

connect();

$description = get_film_description($_GET ['film_id'] );

print_r($description);

echo '<h1>{$description->title}</h1>';
echo '<p>{$description->description}</p>';
?>
```

The output of `print_r($description)`:

```
stdClass Object (
  [film_id] => 49
  [description] => A Emotional Panorama of a Pioneer  //And a Composer who must Escape a Mad Scientist in A Jet Boat
  [title] => BADMAN DAWN
)
```

The output in the browser:

```
<h1>{$description->title}</h1>
<p>{$description->description}</p>
```

Comment: Use double quotes on the strings, not single quotes as in `"<h1>{$description->title}</h1>"`. Single quotes won't interpolate the variables.  Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php for the differences...

Comment: Otherwise, what you're doing looks to be all correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using single quotes around your strings, `PHP` does not parse your variables. You need to use double quotest or concat if you want to parse your variables.

For example:

```
 echo 'Hey $name'; //Output: Hey $name
```

With double quotes:

```
 echo "Hey $name"; //Output: Hey Joe
```

But the best way I think is:

```
 echo "Hey" . $name; //Output: Hey Joe
```

So this will do the job:

```
 echo "<h1>{$description->title}</h1>";
```

As @TecBrat point me, the best, if you use this:

```
echo "<h1>" . $description->title . "</h1>";
```

**NOTE**

Why I've sad, the 3rd is the best? Because, most of us, developers are using IDE to edit our code. Most of IDE has syntax highlighting. So, you know, there is a variable, you can click on it, and will highlight all the assignments, you can check with IDE, is that variable is set, you can CTRL click on that what is show you where do you initialized it, show you if there are more assignments, etc... Very usefull.

Comment: I'd modify your "best" answer as `echo 'Hey' . $name; //Output: Hey Joe!` unless there's a reason that PHP needs to parse the "Hey" string. So the OP would use `echo '<h1>'.$description->title.'</h1>';`

Comment: Thank you for pointing me that. It's more clear. I've edited my code. Merry Christmas! :)